# Error: Callback was already called. when using async waterfall and trying to run program forever

Tags: node.js, async.js

Get this error when calling the code the 2nd time.
Trying to listen to a Queue and publish back to a Queue. Works 1st time but not the 2nd time. Get this error on the done().
I publish a message to the Q through a separate program. It workd fine.
I want this processMessage() in program1 to run forever and Listen to messages in the Q.

I publish a 2nd message to the Q through the separate program. It fails in the called program mq.js with the following error:

```
Error: Callback was already called.
    at /Users/vkbalakr/sports/clip-mc/services/base/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:966:32
        
        at .../mq.js:221:18
```

Calling **program1**:

```
let client;
function processMessage() {
    let steps=[]
    steps.push((done)=> {
        config = "..."
        return done(null, config);
    })
    steps.push((config, done)=> {
        let subscribeToQueue = "xyz"
        mq.subscribeToMq(subscribeToQueue, null,function (err, data, client) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          this.client = client;
          return done(null, data);
        });
    })
    steps.push((data, done) => {
        const publishToTopic = "zxy";
        mq.publishOnMq(publishToTopic, data, client, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          return done(null, data);
        });
      });

      async.waterfall(steps, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error("Final Error caught:", err);
        } else {
          logger.debug("Final Success with result:", result);
        }
      });

}

processMessage()
```

**Called program mq.js**:

```
let client;
function subscribeToMq(subscribeToTopic, client, cb) {
  const steps = [];

  // Connect client - STOMP broker supports STOMP over WebSockets.
  steps.push((done) => {
    // See https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/ for API documentation
    client = new StompJs.Client({....})

    client.onConnect = function (frame) {
      return done(); // Good, it's active
    };

    client.onWebSocketError = function (frame) {
    };

    client.onStompError = function (frame) {
    };
    client.activate();
  });
    
    steps.push((done)=> {
    const subscription = client.subscribe(subscribeToTopic, (message) => {
        const body = message.body;
        if (body !== null && body !== '' && body !== -0) {
          jsonBody = JSON.parse(message.body);
          const jsonBodyParsed = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
          const validationStatus = validateSchema(jsonBodyParsed);//retruna true or false
          if (!validationStatus.code) {
            return done(new Error(validationStatus.errMsg));
          }
          message.ack();
          return done(null, jsonBodyParsed, client); // **<== Fails here on 2nd call ????**
        } else {
          return done();
        }
      },
      headers);
  });

  async.waterfall(steps, (err, result, client) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb(new Error("Error Subscribing"));
    }
    return cb(null, result, client);
  });
}

function publishOnMq(publishToTopic, data, client, cb) {
  const steps = [];
  this.client = client;
  steps.push((done) => {
    if (client !== null) {
      client = new StompJs.Client({
        brokerURL,
        connectHeaders: {
          login: brokerLogin,
          passcode: brokerPasscode,
        },
        debug(str) {
        },
        webSocketFactory() {
          return new WebSocket(brokerURL, this.stompVersions.protocolVersions(), { agent: agent });
        },
        reconnectDelay: 5000,
        heartbeatIncoming: 20000,
        heartbeatOutgoing: 20000,
      });


      client.onConnect = function (frame) {
        return done(); // Good, it's active
      };

      client.onWebSocketError = function (frame) {
      };

      client.onStompError = function (frame) {
      };
      client.activate();
    } else {
      return done();
    }
  });

  // Publish messages
  steps.push((done) => {
    client.publish({
      destination: publishToTopic,
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      skipContentLengthHeader: true,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    client.deactivate();
    done(null, { result: 'published' });
  });

  async.waterfall(steps, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(new Error("Error Publishing"));
      }
      return cb(null, result);
  });
}
```

TIA,

Comment: Have also tried with async.forever and async.until but get the error on the calling program at the done() function. Trying to call the async.waterfall in a never ending loop in the calling program which in turn calls mq.js.

Comment: what is the line of code in `mq.js:221`